# Entity Framework Base Class

Tags: entity-framework, superclass, circular-reference

Having a base class for entity objects I am being faced with the problem of circular reference and base Dependent Role introduction problems wherever I have a composite class of entities:

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime CreationTime {get;set;}
   public User Creator {get; ste;}
}
public class User : Base
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Country BirthPlace {get;set;}
   // rest of the properties
}
public class Country : Base
{
   public string Description {get;set;}
   //rest of the properties
}
```

Any idea of how to overcome that?

Comment: Hi, if my solution answered your question, please mark the question useful, thank you :)

Comment: Thanks mate did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a Mapping class to ignore base class user

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

or

remove User from base and add it in every domain that will need it (example)

```
public class Country : Base
{
   public string Description {get;set;}
   public User Creator {get; set}
   //rest of the properties
}
```